# Getting null in nested elements when deserializing xml

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I'm deserializing my xml which is string, into my classes.
Problem is that part of nested child elements or their attributes return null.

Here is my deserialize function:

```
public static T DeSerialize<T>(this string xml)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API")]
public partial class VideoGames
{
    private GameType[] typesField;

    private Platform platformField;

    private string memoField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("Types", Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Data", IsNullable = false)]
    public GameType[] Types
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typesField= value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Platform", Order = 1)]
    public Platform Platform
    {
        get
        {
            return this.platformField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.platformField= value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Memo
    {
        get
        {
            return this.memoField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.memoField= value;
        }
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API")]
public partial class Platform
{
    private decimal compressedField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Compressed
    {
        get
        {
            return this.compressedField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.compressedField= value;
        }
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API")]
public partial class GameType
{
    private Code[] codeField;

    private string nameField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute("Code", Order = 0)] 
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Category", IsNullable = false)]
    public Code[] Code
    {
        get
        {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.codeField= value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nameField= value;
        }
    }
}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API")]
public partial class Code
{
    private string textField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.textField= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<VideoGames Memo="1">
    <Types>
        <Data Name="RPG">
            <Code>
                <Category Text="TestingData"/>
            </Code>
        </Data>
    </Types>
    <Platform Compressed="3.2876"/>
</VideoGames>
```

And I'm using deserialize like this:

```
string xml = "";//xml string above.
VideoGames a = xml.DeSerialize<VideoGames>();
```

I expect every property in class will have value, but only Memo in VideoGames has value, others are null.

For example: `a.Types` is null, but `a.Memo` is "1".

I have tried all related questions searched by this topic, and none of them work.

Note:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

I have checked this xDoc, it loaded perfectly, nothing was lost.

Comment: Could it be that `Types` and `Platform` are not initialised?

Comment: @bolkayI tried, `this.typesField = new GameType[] { };`, and then I got a null array, not a null.

Comment: I doubt that is a valid way to initialize an array. Can you for example, set `typesField[5]=something?`? In this case, there is nothing in the your array based on your method of initialisation `{}`.

Comment: Oh, I know what's wrong at here. I just tried `this.typesField = new GameType[] { new GameType() };` and I got a GameType array with 1 element in there, a new GameType class with no value. Why deserialize can't do it correctly? My other classes don't have such problem.

Comment: `a.Platform` is null, too. It seems that it can only deserialize top node's attributes now.

Comment: I'm not really sure what wrong but initialising `plaformField=new Platform();` should be a good way to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to diagnose problems in XML deserialization is to *serialize to XML* and compare the observed XML with the required XML.  Usually the problem will be immediately apparent.

If I create and serialize an instance of `VideoGames` as follows:

```
var root = new VideoGames
{
    Types = new []
    {
        new GameType
        {
            Name = "RPG",
            Code = new []
            {
                new Code { Text = "TestingData" },
            }
        },
    },
    Platform = new Platform  { Compressed = 3.2876m, },
};

var xml = root.GetXml(omitStandardNamespaces: true);
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Using the following extension method:

```
public static string GetXml<T>(this T obj, XmlSerializer serializer = null, bool omitStandardNamespaces = false)
{
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = null;
    if (omitStandardNamespaces)
    {
        ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
    }           
    using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }; // For cosmetic purposes.
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            (serializer ?? new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())).Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then the output is:

```
<VideoGames>
  <Types xmlns="http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API">
    <Data Name="RPG">
      <Code>
        <Category Text="TestingData" />
      </Code>
    </Data>
  </Types>
  <Platform Compressed="3.2876" xmlns="http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API" />
</VideoGames>
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VnL2g1).

As you can see, **the child elements `<Types>` and `<Platform>` are all serialized in an [XML namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-qualify-xml-element-and-xml-attribute-names)**, specifically `http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API`.

Your deserialization fails because, in the sample XML, these elements are not in any namespace.

Why is this happening?  It's because all your classes including `VideoGames` have an [`XmlTypeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute applied that specifies a [`Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.namespace?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlTypeAttribute_Namespace):

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.specifiedcompany.com/API")]
public partial class VideoGames
{
}
```

What this attribute does is to specify that *by default, all properties of the type should be serialized into the specified namespace*.  (Compare with [`XmlRootAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute?view=netframework-4.8) which specifies how the root element `<VideoGames>` itself, rather than just its children, is to be serialized.)

If you don't want that, remove the `XmlTypeAttribute.Namespace` setting from your c# classes `VideoGames`, `Platform`, `GameType` and `Code` (demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8uDuRZ)).  If you do want that, modify your XML to include the required namespace as shown in the output XML in this answer.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I just found what causes the problem, it was my class properties' order. I didn't expect these `ORDER` settings could make this problem...
Anyway, I think your namespace removal is a new knowledge to me, but should I click accept this answer? Since this maybe not related to the question.

Comment: @ApexEC - the sample XML in your question has the correct order, which is `<Types>`, then `<Platform>`.  If you have different XML with a different order and need to deserialize that as well, removing the `Order` settings will help.

Comment: The explanation of namespaces was tremendously helpful, thanks! I had generated a .cs class from an .xsd from a .dtd, and the process gave the default namespace of tempuri.org to everything, which made deserialization not work properly. Lifesaver!

Comment: In my case, I needed to blank the namespace of child element, for example: `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "")]
public partial class GameType`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue recently, where it turns out if a single field in a nested XML object was null or missing, or the value in the field couldn't deserialize to the specific type, the List representing the nested elements would just return null.

I tried all sorts of attributes for the fields, trying IsNullable and a bunch of other recommended attributes as mentioned here on stackoverflow, nothing helped.

To fix this, I ended up changing all the fields in my class the XML is being deserialized to type of string.

Hope this helps someone.